# Generate WAR file for Ruby on Rails using JRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I am new to Ruby on rails.I need to generate War file using Jruby for an ROR application and deploy it on Tomcat.I need to implement this on windows environment.
I know it might a basic question ,But any resources on how to do it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `gem install warbler` # --`--pre` if you want to use JRuby 9K (not 1.7)--

**UPDATE:** Warbler 2.0 (JRuby 9K) has been released, for JRuby 1.7 use 1.x

- (optional) `warble config` # to tune the .war generation at *config/warble.rb*
- `jruby -S warble` # generates a .war file for you that you can deploy

Comment: Thank you @kares,But I believe I have to change the adapter for sqliteby Installing 
gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'

After I install the gem, I get below exception,
activerecord-jdbc-adapter is for use with JRuby only
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1
.3.20/lib/arjdbc/sqlite3/adapter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `l
oad_java_part' for ArJdbc:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-j
dbc-adapter-1.3.20/lib/arjdbc/sqlite3.rb:2:in `require'

Comment: well yes - its kind of an assumption that you're able to locally run with JRuby `rails c` or `rails s`. some gems such as *activerecord* need JRuby counterparts such as *activerecord-jdbc-adapter* you should have those set if you've generated the Rails app under JRuby (generate an empty one and check the *Gemfile*). for your issue add `platform: jruby` specified for the AR-JDBC gem so its not loaded under MRI.

Comment: thank you kares ,  the reason i was gettin errors was because i was trying to install rails on jruby.... and run it directly as rails commands. I was successfuly able to by using only jruby -S commands instead of installing rails on jruby